# Tensorflow problem in Pycharm Virtual environment: TypeError: 'Model' object is not iterable

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, virtualenv

I use Python 3.5, Tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0, Keras 2.2.4 in ubuntu. When I use system interpreter in Pycharm, the code is run without any problem. But, when I create a virtual environment in Pycharm and install the same versions of all necessary packages (OpenCV, Sklearn, pandas, Keras, Tensorflow), it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/ehsan/48BE4782BE476810/AA_MY_PYTHON_CODE/MultiLable_MultiTask_Light_Examples/CodeTwo/2_Main_Code_Training_Multitask_Network.py", line 338, in <module>
    base_model, multi_model, feature_map = multi_model(loss_list, test_metrics, dd)
  File "/media/ehsan/48BE4782BE476810/AA_MY_PYTHON_CODE/MultiLable_MultiTask_Light_Examples/CodeTwo/2_Main_Code_Training_Multitask_Network.py", line 40, in multi_model
    _, base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(175, 100, 3))
TypeError: 'Model' object is not iterable
```

I tried to reinstall Tensorflow and Keras. Also, I recreated the virtual environment. But, I got the same error while using the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the model from TensorFlow instead of Keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

instead of

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

Comment: Actually, I want to train. So I changed the "from keras.models import Model" to  "from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model", but the same error appears. As I mentioned in the post, the code is run without any problem with system interpreter, but when I create a virtualenv in Pycharm and run it. I got the error. So, the problem is with some packages that I need to add or change.